# Access ApplicationCookies Identity Claims in Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to add some cookies in a ActionFilter this works for all call less the initial oauth redirect. Is there a way i can access the ApplicationCookie Claims in the call?

I can see the data in the HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication but i cannot figure out how to access it.

```
  public class CookieActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

// NULL On Initial Login
            if (identity != null)
            {
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its accessible via

HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity